# excel vba clear all refedit controls in a userform

Tags: excel, vba, reset, userform

I need to add a Reset button to a userform I am working on in EXCEL VBA. I have the following code that does most of the work, however, I haven't figured out how to clear the refedit controls. This is what I have so far:

===

```
'Reset Button
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    
        Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
            Case "TextBox"
                ctrl.Text = ""
            Case "ComboBox"
                    ctrl.ListIndex = -1
            Case "OptionButton", "CheckBox"
                    ctrl.Value = False
            Case "ListBox"
            For i = 0 To ctrl.ListCount - 1
                If ctrl.Selected(i) Then
                    ctrl.Selected(i) = False
                End If
            Next i
        End Select
    Next
    
End Sub
```

===

This works for the textboxes, checkboxes, etc. I have tried adding 2 different pieces of code to this sub for clear the refedit controls.

## 1 :

```
For i = 0 To crtl.RefEdit - 1
      ctrl.Selected(i) = vbNullString
Next i
```

===

## 2:

```
Case "RefEdit"
     ctrl.RefEdit = vbNullString
```

===

Neither works as desired. Any suggestions are appreciated!!

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Dim ctrl As Control
Dim i As Long

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    Select Case TypeName(ctrl)
        Case "TextBox":                     ctrl.Text = vbNullString
        Case "ComboBox":                    ctrl.ListIndex = -1
        Case "OptionButton", "CheckBox":    ctrl.Value = False
        Case "RefEdit":                     ctrl.Value = vbNullString
        Case "ListBox":                     For i = 0 To ctrl.ListCount - 1
                                                ctrl.Selected(i) = False
                                            Next i
    End Select
Next ctrl
```

Comment: Does the `ListBox` case work, with that formatting? (I've never seen it like that before)

Comment: @BruceWayne It will, yes.  And this type of formatting isn't necessary, just a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed hard to know what you need to do to clear controls, because you're working with late-bound calls against a `Variant/Object` that are only resolved at run-time, i.e. the editor can't help you discover the objects' members - you don't get the IntelliSense dropdown when you type that `.` dot.

On top of that, `TypeName` is making your code vulnerable to typos, and in the extraordinarily unlikely event that you have a 3rd-party ActiveX control library referenced that defines a `TextBox` or `ListBox` or `RefEdit` class/control, you have no way to tell exactly which one you're looking at.

Make type checks with `TypeOf...Is` instead, and consider casting the `ctrl` control to the appropriate type, so that you keep all the code early-bound, strongly-typed; you get compile-time validation, intellisense and autocomplete all the way - note that becasue of how `TypeOf...Is` works, you need to put the conditions in each `Case` branch, so you `Select Case True` instead:

```
Private Sub ClearControls()
    Dim ctrl As MSForms.Control
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        Select Case True

            Case TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox
                Dim txtBox As MSForms.TextBox
                Set txtBox = ctrl
                txtBox.Text = vbNullString

            Case TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.ComboBox
                Dim cmbBox As MSForms.ComboBox
                Set cmbBox = ctrl
                cmbBox.ListIndex = -1

            Case TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.OptionButton
                Dim optBtn As MSForms.OptionButton
                Set optBtn = ctrl
                optBtn.Value = False

            Case TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.CheckBox
                Dim chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox
                Set chkBox = ctrl
                chkBox.Value = False

            Case TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.ListBox
                Dim lstBox As MSForms.ListBox
                Set lstBox = ctrl
                Dim i As Long
                For i = 0 To lstBox.ListCount - 1
                    lstBox.Selected(i) = False
                Next

            Case TypeOf ctrl Is RefEdit.RefEdit
                Dim refEditCtrl As RefEdit.RefEdit
                Set refEditCtrl = ctrl
                refEditCtrl.Value = vbNullString

        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```